# How to translate enum values?

Tags: javascript, enums

I'm working on Node.js. In material.js model I have the following enum

```
var CONDITIONS = {
    FULLYWORKING: 'FULLY_WORKING',
    DETERIORATED: 'DETERIORATED',
    INREPAIR: 'IN_REPAIR',
    DEFECTIVE: 'DEFECTIVE',
};
```

I use it to show it in a form with Vue.js.

```
select#condition.form-control(name='condition', required, v-model='materialEdit.condition')

option(v-for='item,key in conditions' :value='key') {{item}}
```

The thing is I would like to  have to option the translate the values to another language. I'm currently using i18n to translate the website. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are a ton of I18N options in JS; just pick one. (Not an enum, just an object, fwiw.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over an object like that. Normally you would call an enum like this:

```
var conditions = [FULLYWORKING, DETERIORATED, INREPAIR, DEFECTIVE]
option(v-for='(item,key) in conditions' :value='key') {{CONDITIONS.item}}
```

Another options is to use `Object.keys(CONDITIONS)` like this:

```
option(v-for='(item,key) in Object.keys(CONDITIONS)' :value='key') {{CONDITIONS.item}}
```